# Time interpolation for a GPS route based on known

Tags: javascript, math, time, gps, interpolation

I need to interpolate the time for a GPS route based on the time of some known points.

I started by calculating the distance between the points and the average speed to overcome the known points. And when trying to interpolate time for the remaining points, a problem arose. Even though I'm calculating the time, it doesn't seem right. Is it necessary to add a known time to the interpolated time? But then if the point was made ahead of the point with unknown time, then it will be the wrong time. How to calculate the time in this case?

```js
var DatesPicTaken = [
    {
      "lat": 41.29255161333331,
      "lng": 69.28619298,
      "Date": "2023:05:18 11:49:28"
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.291602321666668,
      "lng": 69.28423231666667,
      "Date": "2023:05:18 11:53:19"
    },

];
  
var displayedCoordinates = [
    {
      "lat": 41.29255161333333,
      "lng": 69.28619297,
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.291602321666666,
      "lng": 69.28423231666666,
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.29161988166667,
      "lng": 69.284010615,
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.29156611166667,
      "lng": 69.28317041333334,
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.29196597,
      "lng": 69.281372495,
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.292269688333334,
      "lng": 69.28039114166667,
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.292828091666664,
      "lng": 69.27999861833334,
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.29282566,
      "lng": 69.27999543166666,
    },
    {
      "lat": 41.29220384833334,
      "lng": 69.27896445833333,

    },
    {
      "lat": 41.291491555,
      "lng": 69.27798562,

    },
    {
      "lat": 41.289875985,
      "lng": 69.275506085,

    },
    {
      "lat": 41.28964917,
      "lng": 69.27521590333333,

    },
    {
      "lat": 41.289234936666666,
      "lng": 69.27466261333333,

    },
    {
      "lat": 41.289234936666666,
      "lng": 69.27466261333333,

    }
];

function calculateDistance(route) {

    if (route.length < 2) {
        return 0; // Если в маршруте меньше двух точек, расстояние равно 0
    }

    let totalDistance = 0;
    const earthRadius = 6371e3; // metres

    for (let i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
        const startPoint = route[i];
        const endPoint = route[i + 1];

        const lat1 = startPoint.lat;
        const lat2 = endPoint.lat;
        const lon1 = startPoint.lng;
        const lon2 = endPoint.lng;

        const φ1 = lat1 * Math.PI/180; // φ, λ in radians
        const φ2 = lat2 * Math.PI/180;
        const Δφ = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI/180;
        const Δλ = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI/180;

        const a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
                Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
                Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
        const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

        totalDistance += earthRadius * c; // in metres
    }

    return totalDistance;
}

function getAvgSpeed(route) {
    if (route.length < 2) {
        return 0; // Если в маршруте меньше двух точек, расстояние равно 0
    }

    let speed = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
        const Date = route[i].Date;

        let dateParts = Date.split(" ");
    
        let timeP = dateParts[1].split(":");

        let hr = parseInt(timeP[0]);
        let min = parseInt(timeP[1]);
        let sec = parseInt(timeP[2]);

        let distance = calculateDistance(route);
        let time = (hr * 3600 + min * 60 + sec) / 3600;

        let formula = distance / time;

        speed += formula;
    }

    return speed / (route.length - 1);
}

function secondsToHms(seconds) {
    let d = Number(seconds);
  
    if (d <= 0) {
        return '00:00:00'
    } else {
        let h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
        let m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
        let s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
    
        let hDisplay = h <= 9 ? '0'+ h+':' : h+ ":";
        let mDisplay = m <= 9 ? '0'+ m+':' : m+ ":";
        let sDisplay = s <= 9 ? '0'+ s : s;
    
        return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
    }
}


function interpolateTime(route, knownDates) {
    if (route.length  < 2) {
      return 0; // Если в маршруте или в массиве известных дат меньше двух точек, интерполяция невозможна
    }

    let speed = getAvgSpeed(knownDates);

    console.log('speed:', speed)
  
    for (let i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
        const startPoint = route[i];
        const endPoint = route[i + 1];

        const distance = calculateDistance([startPoint, endPoint])
        console.log('distance:', distance)

        console.log('time:', distance / speed )
        const time = secondsToHms(distance / speed);
        console.log('time converted:', time)

        route[i].Date = time;
    }

    return route;
}

var interpolated = interpolateTime(displayedCoordinates, DatesPicTaken);
  
console.log(interpolated);
```

Comment: I think you get wrong calculating the speed. The *time* on speed formula (but also space) is the *elapsed time* (and *distance*). So correct your code to get the elapsed time.